# Retry Connection to RabbitMQ and MongoDB in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit, spring-mongodb, spring-retry

I am using spring and want to retry obtaining the connection to RabbitMQ and MongoDB if it fails.
I know it works this way for a sql database:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4779#issuecomment-305482782

However i don’t know which classes to wrap for RabbitMQ and MongoDB.

I also tried to wrap the ConnectionFactory for RabbitMQ but  AbstractConnectionFactory has some final Methods I can not override to pass the call to the delegate-factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For RabbitMQ, on the consumer side, the connection will be recovered automatically based on the listener container configuration (by default it will try every 5 seconds to reconnect).

For publishing messsages, you can configure a suitably configured `RetryTemplate` (from spring-retry) in the `RabbitTemplate`.

For Mongo, you can use a `RetryTemplate` or a `@Retryable` annotation within your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. With in your code you mean when i use a method of the mongorepository?

Comment: Yes; put the call in a `@Retryable` method or make the call within `RetryTemplate.execute(c -> { ... })`.